# Expand a data.frame/table

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

Let's say I have a data.frame/table which I want to "expand", such that each row transforms into a sequence of repeat rows (which can be described as a group), except for a new column which will have the same values in all groups.

So, taking the following dataframe, we want to expand it by column `id`, such that each row is now repeated, but with a new column `q` which repeats from 1-4 for each group.

The way I've found to do this is to build a second dataframe based on the first one's column `id` and with the new column values, and then joining it to the original:

```r
library(dplyr)

set.seed(42)

a <- data.frame(id = 1:5,
                value = runif(5))
a
#>   id     value
#> 1  1 0.9148060
#> 2  2 0.9370754
#> 3  3 0.2861395
#> 4  4 0.8304476
#> 5  5 0.6417455

b <- data.frame(id = rep(a$id, each = 4),
                q = 1:4)

left_join(a, b, by = "id")
#>    id     value q
#> 1   1 0.9148060 1
#> 2   1 0.9148060 2
#> 3   1 0.9148060 3
#> 4   1 0.9148060 4
#> 5   2 0.9370754 1
#> 6   2 0.9370754 2
#> 7   2 0.9370754 3
#> 8   2 0.9370754 4
#> 9   3 0.2861395 1
#> 10  3 0.2861395 2
#> 11  3 0.2861395 3
#> 12  3 0.2861395 4
#> 13  4 0.8304476 1
#> 14  4 0.8304476 2
#> 15  4 0.8304476 3
#> 16  4 0.8304476 4
#> 17  5 0.6417455 1
#> 18  5 0.6417455 2
#> 19  5 0.6417455 3
#> 20  5 0.6417455 4
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is there a more direct way of doing this? In my example above I've used `dplyr`, but I can just as easily adopt `data.table` syntax if that's easier.

Comment: If any of the three answers to your question could be used, then you should consider marking one of them as accepted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with the function `crossing` from the `tidyr` package.

```r
library(tidyr)

a <- tibble(
  id = 1:5, value = runif(5)
)

crossing(a, q = 1:4)
#> # A tibble: 20 x 3
#>       id value     q
#>    <int> <dbl> <int>
#>  1     1 0.222     1
#>  2     1 0.222     2
#>  3     1 0.222     3
#>  4     1 0.222     4
#>  5     2 0.262     1
#>  6     2 0.262     2
#>  7     2 0.262     3
#>  8     2 0.262     4
#>  9     3 0.284     1
#> # … with 10 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2020-01-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

If we need to `rep`licate the rows, it can be easily done with `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
uncount(a, 4) %>% 
     mutate(q = rowid(id))
```

---

Or another option is create a `list` column of 'q' and then `unnest`

```
a %>% 
   mutate(q = list(1:4)) %>%
   unnest(q)
```

Or in `base R`

```
transform(a[rep(seq_len(nrow(a)), 4), ], q = sequence(table(id)))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(a)[, .(q = 1:4),.(id, value)]
```

Or replicate the rows first

```
setDT(a)[rep(seq_len(.N), .N)][, q := rep(1:4, length.out = .N)][]
```

Comment: What I meant by "more direct" was one which didn't require building another dataframe/table, expanding `a` directly.

Comment: @Wasabi Wouldn't `uncount(a, 4) %>% 
     mutate(q = rowid(id))` be more direct?

Comment: Ah, these new methods with `uncount` or `unnest` are perfect.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` alternative:

```
setDT(a)
a[CJ(id = id, q = 1:4), on = .(id)]
```

Base `R`:

```
expand_grid(a, q = 1:4)
```